# Owin OpenIdConnect Active Directory HttpContext.GetOwinContext doesn't open microsoftonlin login page

Tags: active-directory, owin

I'm trying to use Owin and OpenIdConnect to authenticate users via active directory (office 365 online).  I've followed this [example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/) and I managed to create a new MVC test project and get it all working. (Settings for AD app id, tenant, Web config etc all fine).

I'm now trying to add that functionality into my existing ASP.net mvc application and I can't get the dang thing to work.

This is what I have:  An Account Controller with a "void" action like this (from the example that works in my PoC but not in my actual application):

```
public void SignIn()
    {
        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
```

When this action is invoked, I expect the browser to be directed to: login.microsoftonline.com..., but instead it opens this page: https://localhost:44301/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fSignIn

It's like it's calling some sort of redirect somewhere and I can't see where.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had to do 2 things:

1. Remove the WebMatrix dll's from the references (apparently nuget package for mvc put it there, so it might come back)
2. Remove authentication mode="Forms" from web.config

Thanks.